# Folder Approval Status doesn't update with Workflow Action

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, content-approval

I have the following workflow snippet:

[image: Workflow Snippet]

However, the `Set content approval` piece isn't actually updating the Folder's status to Approved (it is remaining "Pending" after the workflow completes). Is there a different way I need to go about setting this for folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that after setting the status of the folder to `Approved` I was then changing the workflow status, which functions as modifying the metadata for the folder. By switching the order and setting the workflow status before Approving, the folder now properly displays as `Approved` when the workflow runs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Content Approval and SharePoint Designer workflow with 2013 workflow platform type.

I have reproduced it.

You need to use the **SharePoint workflow 2010 platform type** instead. Per my testing results, it works.